# How can you host a desktop application in cloud?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cloud, desktop-application

I have created a windows(desktop) application (large) using C#.Net, VB.Net & SQL Server 2005.

I need to move this application to cloud platform. I've not much knowledge regd Cloud.

Every thing I read about cloud, hints that applications developed using ASP.Net 
or Web applications/sites can only be hosted on cloud. 
Since, my application is using WinForms (desktop), 
I am doubtful whether the application will work on cloud platform.

Can this application be hosted in Cloud? 
Or should I recreate the entire application using ASP.Net to run in Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deliver this on Amazon Cloud using Citrix XenApp. AWS has Citrix XenApp AMI's in its marketplace. You can host your C#/VB.net on Amazon EC2, upgrade and migrate your MSSQL to 2012/2008 and host it on another Amazon EC2. Have Citrix XenApp installed on AWS and deliver your desktop app to your customers via Xenapp.

Answer (score 2):

it would be more interesting if you moved only the DATA components of the App to the cloud, so your (heavy) clients could use the cloud as a LAN extension. Cheaper and no code impact, just addressing the dat source in the new location.
Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused as to what actually gets hosted "in the cloud" (a term I really despise, to be honest).  Essentially your desktop application remains a regular desktop application, but you can offload data and/or processing "to the cloud" and your desktop application accesses it, usually using a web service.

See the [Amazon E3 overview](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Few options to host windows(WinForms/WPF) app in cloud are -

1. Appstream2 (AWS)
2. Windows Virtual Desktop (Azure)
3. Citrix Virtual Apps and Desktops

Comment: Do I need to pay AZURE for hosting my desktop-application?